# Armadillo random number generator only generating zeros (Windows, MSYS2)

Tags: c++, armadillo

The following test program is supposed to generate a vector with 5 random elements, but only contains zeroes when I compile and run it on my machine.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <armadillo>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using arma::vec;

int main()
{
    arma::arma_rng::set_seed(1);
    vec v = arma::randu<vec>(5);
    cout << v << endl;
    cout << v(0) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Compilation/output

```
$ g++ main.cpp -o example -std=c++11 -O2 -larmadillo

$ ./example.exe
        0
        0
        0
        0
        0

0
```

I'm on Windows 10, using gcc ((Rev1, Built by MSYS2 project) 8.2.1 20181214) and Armadillo (9.200.6) from MSYS2.

Packages (pacman in mingw64 subsystem):

```
mingw64/mingw-w64-x86_64-armadillo 9.200.6-1
mingw64/mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc-8.3.0-1
```

Any idea what could cause this?

I have an inkling that this might be because I'm using the MSYS2 version of Armadillo, but I'm not sure, and haven't tested compiling the library myself (yet).

**EDIT:** I have an inkling that this is related to MSYS somehow, so I opened an issue over here: https://github.com/msys2/MINGW-packages/issues/5019

Comment: Works fine one Debian stable with gcc 6.3.0 and Armadillo 7.600.2.